# How do i add a project for Unit tests in c# in vs2010?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I must be missing something, i have VS2010 Premium.

Under Templates, Test Projects -> Test Documents, there is only 1 thing listed called 'Test Project' If i select his, it adds the Unit testing framework to the solution, but the project it adds is for VB.NET --- does c# not have this option?

thanks :-)

Comment: Microsoft AI decided that you are so awesome, that you do not need unit tests. I wanna be you man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't look under Root->Test projects.  Look at Root->Visual C#->Test->Test Project.

Comment: Thank you.  I do have Visual C#->Test --- but when i select it, it displays 'No items found' -- and i just did a fresh install of vs2010 :-(  i have tried repair templates and re-install -- is there any way to just get this template that you know of?  Thanks for your reply :0)

Comment: Ah, ok i see now tho its odd.  I had to select 4.0 to see the c# testing project (VB.NET allows you to select testing project when targeting 3.5)  .. .thank you !